# For what reason might my local space consumption on Dropbox not match the server's?

Tags: dropbox, synchronization

I have three machines (1 Mac, 2 Linux) synchronized with Dropbox. On all the local machines, my Dropbox consumption shows around ~84G consumption:

```
me@macbook:~$ du -hs ~/Dropbox
 84G    /Users/me/Dropbox
```

Yet on the Dropbox website, they show me as consuming around 132G on my Dropbox, and have done consistently for several days. 84G vs. 132G seems like too large a gap to be down to counting variations, etc.

Of course I've raised a support ticket with Dropbox, but am so far struggling to communicate the problem clearly. I don't have Selective Sync turned on - in other words, all of my folders are being synchronized to my machines.

Are there any other reasons I might have missed for why there might be such a large discrepancy?

**Edit** 2012-10-21: For future reference; after a week's long back-and-forth with Dropbox support, they admitted there was a bug on their side and fixed it. My space utilisation went back to normal. In fairness, they did refund the extra I'd had to pay to upgrade my allocation and regain syncing ability. Took a while, and the bug is worrying: but support did do the right thing in the end.

Comment: From what you are describing, looks more like a bug than a hidden feature.

Comment: Alex, yes, I think so. Just trying to rule out any stupidity on my part :) Thx.

Comment: You should have added the solution as an answer rather than updating question.